# How can I sign out of my app using google sign-in

Tags: google-signin

I have followed the instructions here.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
<script>
    function signOut() {
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
           auth2.signOut().then(function () {
           console.log('User signed out.');
        });
    }
</script>
```

and it's all ok.  but on another page within my site (mine is not a SPA) I can't sign out because auth2 doesn't exist and if I load it like so

```
   gapi.load('auth2', function () ...
```

I still won't be able to sign out because the auth2.signOut() function doesn't exist on this other page.  Could someone advise the correct way of handling this?